# How to display specific records on a report based on data in a field

Tags: validation, ms-access

I have 3 reports on MS Access that are all based from 1 table (the database) and 1 Form (data entry).

I want each of the 3 forms to display records based on certain data in one of the fields in the table.

For example: If the data in field [City] is "Los Angeles" then I want a report to only display records which have "Los Angeles" in the [City] field.

Comment: Please write a filter / where clause in your report query, here is the sample http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/filter_report.htm

Comment: @Hiten004, thank you for your link. It is a good approach. If you care, make it an answer and I will vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample that can help you from the link [www.blueclaw-db.com](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/filter_report.htm)

```
Filter Report Records Using Form Field Parameter Example:

Select M_Employees.Name, M_Employees.Emp_Number, M_Employees.Address 
From M_Employees 
Where 
Forms!F_Emp!Emp_Combo=0 or Forms!F_Emp!Emp_Combo = M_Employees.Employee_ID;
```

Hope this can help other like @joe